# Not found in axis. I am failing to drop a columns from my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So basically I am trying to drop 2 columns from my dataframe. One of them works and one does not
Here is my python code

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv("testfile2.csv")
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

dummies = pd.get_dummies((df.town))
merged = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis='columns')
final = merged.drop(['town', 'robbinsville'], axis='columns')
print(final)
```

When I try to print at the end, I run into this error:
KeyError: "['robbinsville'] not found in axis"
And this is true of all the keys in the csv

Here is the csv:

```
town, area, price,
'monroe township', 2600, 550000,
'monroe township', 3000, 560000,
'monroe township', 3200, 610000,
'monroe township', 3600, 680000,
'monroe township', 4000, 725000,
'west_windsor', 2600, 585000,
'west_windsor', 2800, 615000,
'west_windsor', 3300, 650000,
'west_windsor', 3600, 710000,
'robbinsville', 2600, 575000,
'robbinsville', 2000, 600000,
'robbinsville', 3100, 620000,
'robbinsville', 3600, 695000,
```

I don't think it's a typo, what am I doing wrong?
Merged will have the extra columns from the concat, and I would like to remove both.
I am able to remove town, but not any of the new created columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column name actually has single-quotes in it. Just add them (escaped, of course) to `robbinsville`:

```py
final = merged.drop(['town', '\'robbinsville\''], axis=1)
```

However, a better solution would be to remove the single-quotes from the data right after loading it, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("testfile2.csv")
df['town'] = df['town'].str.strip("'")
...
```

Comment: That edit worked, could you expand on that though, I don't quite understand

Comment: Because the raw CSV file has single-quotes in it...and apparently `read_csv` doesn't automatically remove them. Please see my answer again - I added a much better solution.

Comment: Sorry I meant to validate that your answer helped, thank you!